# selenium Web driver explicit wait not working....while running code it is not detecting frame or other element

Tags: java, selenium

Selenium Web driver explicit wait not working.... While running code it is not detecting frame or other element.. Please look at following points

1. When I debug code sometimes explicit wait works and detect frame and clicks on element inside frame.
2. When I run the code explicit wait doesn't work at all even if I give 10 minutes wait. It fails to detect frame.
3. Before going for fram, I even use explicit wait for page to load.. Explicit wait for page ready state is working.
4. If I use use Thread.sleep(--) for 3 mins then run the code then it is working fine..i.e detecting frame and clicks on element inside frame.

Exception:

```
16:24:51,946 ERROR Keyword:199 - WaitForVisible : threw error (frame not available)
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 120 seconds waiting for frame to be available: contentAreaFrame
Build info: version: '2.46.0', revision: '87c69e2', time: '2015-06-04 16:17:10'
System info: host: 'infpw05183', ip: '172.25.35.212', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.6.0_35'
Session ID: 9aef5d67-f64a-4443-8946-547b59d8039c
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, version=42.0, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=true, handlesAlerts=true, nativeEvents=false, webStorageEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true}]
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.timeoutException(WebDriverWait.java:80)
    at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:229)
    at com.lntinfotech.fast.common.webdriver.keywords.impl.WaitForVisible.waitForVisible(WaitForVisible.java:150)
    at com.lntinfotech.fast.common.webdriver.keywords.impl.WaitForVisible.execute(WaitForVisible.java:40)
    at com.lntinfotech.fast.common.keywords.Keyword.processKeyword(Keyword.java:194)
    at com.lntinfotech.fast.common.processFiles.ProcessKDT.process(ProcessKDT.java:187)
    at com.lntinfotech.fast.common.processFiles.CFProcessHelper.executeKDT(CFProcessHelper.java:145)
    at com.lntinfotech.fast.common.processFiles.CFProcessHelper.executeKDT(CFProcessHelper.java:95)
    at com.lntinfotech.fast.common.processFiles.CFProcessHelper.execute(CFProcessHelper.java:53)
    at com.lntinfotech.fast.processFiles.ProcessControlFile.process(ProcessControlFile.java:103)
    at com.lntinfotech.fast.FASTCore.execute(FASTCore.java:86)
    at com.lntinfotech.fast.FASTJavaMain.startFASTExecution(FASTJavaMain.java:88)
    at com.lntinfotech.fast.FASTJavaMain.main(FASTJavaMain.java:27)
16:24:57,439 ERROR ProcessKDT:196 - Keyword execution failed!!
```

My java webdriver Code:

```
private Message waitForVisible(String guiObject) {
    WebDriverWait wait;
    //added for frame
    if(isFrame!=null){
        try{
            System.out.println("waitseconds are : "+waitSeconds);

            waitForPageLoad(GlobalState.getWebDriver());    

            System.out.println("before explicit wait : "+System.currentTimeMillis());
            wait = new WebDriverWait(GlobalState.getWebDriver(), 120,2000);
            //Thread.sleep(2000);
            System.out.println("before element");
            //  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id(propertyVal.toString())));
            wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt("contentAreaFrame"));             //exception occurs after this line      
            System.out.println("after element");
            //waitForPageLoad(GlobalState.getWebDriver());  

            System.out.println("after explicit wait : "+System.currentTimeMillis());

            //  System.out.println("finding frame");
            GlobalState.getWebDriver().findElement(byObject);
            //  System.out.println("complete finding frame");

            message=Constants.SUCCESS_MESSAGE;
            System.out.println("frame found");
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new Exception("frame not available");
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
    }               

}


protected void waitForPageLoad(WebDriver driver){
    System.out.println("waiting for doc to load");
    ExpectedCondition<Boolean> expectation = new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
            return ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete");
        }
    };

    Wait<WebDriver> wait1 = new WebDriverWait(GlobalState.getWebDriver(),waitSeconds,1000);
    try {
        System.out.println("waiting for page to load");
        wait1.until(expectation);
        System.out.println("page loaded sucessfully");
    } catch(Throwable error) {
        System.out.println("Timeout waiting for Page Load Request to complete.");
    }


}
}
```

Comment: have you tried just using to wait for frame to appear? : wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("contentAreaFrame")));

Comment: yes...i already tried it but not working

Comment: following is the error if i try as per your option                                                 java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Number   at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler$FrameInfoToStackFrame.apply(ErrorHandler.java:297)
 at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler$FrameInfoToStackFrame.apply(ErrorHandler.java:1)
 at com.google.common.collect.Iterators$8.transform(Iterators.java:799)
 at com.google.common.collect.TransformedIterator.next(TransformedIterator.java:48)............    on that line

Comment: Can you provide URL or HTML for the page?

Comment: sorry...i cant share the html or url....even if i share url it will ask for login credential and i cant provide login credentials

Comment: How can I help you then? Your URL is it for any startup where I can signUp?